# How to make an AWS S3 file public accessible using AW S3 SDK's createPresignedPost method?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case to keep the AWS S3 Bucket Private as default but,
Make certain objects Public while uploading to AWS S3.

I am using the following code to sign the AWS S3 url using and ACL setting as `public-read` -

```
module.exports.generateS3PostSignedUrl = async (bucketName, bucketKey, objectExpiry) => {

    let s3Client = new AWS.S3({
        region: 'some-region'
    });

    let signingParams = {
        Expires: objectExpiry,
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Fields: {
            key: bucketKey,
        },
        Conditions: [
            ['acl', 'public-read']   
        ],
        ACL: 'public-read'
    }

    let s3createPresignedPost = util.promisify(s3Client.createPresignedPost).bind(s3Client);
    let signedUrl = await s3createPresignedPost(signingParams);

    return signedUrl;
};
```

**Request while uploading -**

[image]

I am able to upload the file to AWS S3, if I remove the conditions array in signing params,
but the file is still not public when I click its url.
I believe I have done something wrong code on `signingParams` part.

**Ref -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property

[Upload file to s3 with POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888301/upload-file-to-s3-with-post)

Comment: did you try creating a signed url for getting the file, or are u trying a non signed url?

Comment: I tried getting the object from Console by clicking the `Object URL` link, If I make it Public from console it opens else, returns an xml error, need to achieve the Make Public while uploading to S3

Comment: no need to make it public, creating a signed url should do the trick

Comment: and you are not creating a IAM user with access keys to write the file?

Comment: no signed url involved for getting the object, the plan is to use the bucket prefix and the file name to view the public object

Comment: I am using an IAM Role to generate the createPresignedPost url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204860/discussion-between-vipul-dessai-and-aniruddha-raje).

Comment: I suspect you also need to specify the ACL when performing the upload, not just in the signed portion.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Any way to control from backend? Cause Frontend is out of server control while the browser js code uploads using the signed url

Comment: What you get? when you do get Object? from the code itself?

Comment: The frontend has the bucket name and prefix stored, we just change the image names to get the objects.

Answer (score 1):

The order of parameters matters here.  Put acl parameter before the file and it should work; otherwise S3 just ignores the value you provided.

Below are the example screenshots with different placement of parameters in form-data.

Also, be sure to give execute the createPresignedPost by a user with `s3:PutObjectAcl` and `s3:PutObject` permissions.

[The correct order of form-data parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuvnG.png)

[The same request but with `acl` parameter being placed after `file` (Ignored by S3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5thl.png)

Comment: You mean while signing the URL? Or while uploading?
Can you post the correct script?

Comment: @Ani I meant the uploading part. Updated my answer with a bit more details and my requests screenshots. Please take a look at those